# getting empty UITable with AFNetworking JSON Parsing

Tags: iphone, json, ios6, youtube-api, afnetworking

I am trying to parse JSON data with AFNetworking AFJSONRequestOperation. But i am getting an empty UITable for some reason.

I managed to do it without AFNetworking.

Could someone please have a look at my code [Google Drive](http://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B1EPIKZI6a5sSzVWdXh6VU1POWs/edit?usp=sharing)

```
 #import "AFNetworking.h"


    #import "AFJSONRequestOperation.h"

    @interface KKViewController ()

    @end

@implementation KKViewController

@synthesize  movies = _movies, count = _count;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.movies = [[NSArray alloc] init];

   // get data from youtube

 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL0l3xlkh7UnvLdr0Zz3XZZuP2tENy_qaP?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {



        self.movies = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.video"];

        // NSLog(@@, video)

        //


        self.count = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.video.thumbnail"];
        [self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
        [self.tableView setHidden:NO];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }];

    [operation start];





    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{



    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    if (self.movies && self.movies.count) {
        return self.movies.count;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }


}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellID = @"Cell Identifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    NSDictionary *movie = [self.movies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    NSDictionary *countt = [self.count objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [movie objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [movie objectForKey:@"uploader"];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[countt objectForKey:@"hqDefault"]];
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];

    return cell;
}




/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

@end


  [1]: https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B1EPIKZI6a5sSzVWdXh6VU1POWs/edit?usp=sharing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you should move you initiation code from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear
2. numberOfSectionInTableView should return 1 and not 0